# Integration by transformation

Tags: integration

For $s\in [0,1]$, I can compute this integral,

$$\int \frac{sx^2(1-x)}{1-sx^2}dx$$

by ignoring the denominator and computing $\int sx^2(1-x)dx$, as the difference is almost negligible. However, I am wondering if we can do some transformation that will help keep the denominator for integration. For example, if $x=rcos\theta$, the denominator would be $1-sr^2cos^2\theta$, but I am not sure if this simplifies to anything useful. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot compute the integral by "ignoring the denominator"..

Comment: Try $u=1-sx^2$ or $u=sx^2$.

Comment: Thanks! Well, I was not looking for an exact solution as I was trying to see how the area was growing. The approximation was crude. I was thinking if there was some coordinate transformation (like polar, hyperbolic etc.) where the integral was more nice to evaluate.

Answer (score 2):

$$\int\frac{sx^2(1-x)}{1-sx^2}\space\text{d}x=s\left[\int\frac{x-1}{s(sx^2-1)}\space\text{d}x+\int\frac{x}{s}\space\text{d}x-\int\frac{1}{s}\space\text{d}x\right]=$$
$$\int\frac{x-1}{sx^2-1}\space\text{d}x+\int x\space\text{d}x-\int 1\space\text{d}x=\int\frac{x-1}{sx^2-1}\space\text{d}x+\frac{x^2}{2}-x=$$
$$\int\frac{x}{sx^2-1}\space\text{d}x-\int\frac{1}{sx^2-1}\space\text{d}x+\frac{x^2}{2}-x=$$

---

Substitute $u=sx^2-1$ and $\text{d}u=2sx\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\frac{1}{2s}\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u-\int\frac{1}{sx^2-1}\space\text{d}x+\frac{x^2}{2}-x=\frac{1}{2s}\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u+\int\frac{1}{1-sx^2}\space\text{d}x+\frac{x^2}{2}-x=$$

---

Substitute $p=x\sqrt{s}$ and $\text{d}p=\sqrt{s}\space\text{d}x$:

---

$$\frac{1}{2s}\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u+\frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}\int\frac{1}{1-p^2}\space\text{d}p+\frac{x^2}{2}-x=$$
$$\frac{\ln\left|u\right|}{2s}+\frac{\text{arctanh}\left(p\right)}{\sqrt{s}}+\frac{x^2}{2}-x+\text{C}=$$
$$\frac{\ln\left|sx^2-1\right|}{2s}+\frac{\text{arctanh}\left(x\sqrt{s}\right)}{\sqrt{s}}+\frac{x^2}{2}-x+\text{C}$$

Comment: Thanks a lot Jan! This helps, although I was thinking if there was some coordinate transformation (like polar, hyperbolic etc.) where the integral was more nice to evaluate.

Comment: I think this is a simple way, without using polar or hyperbolic substitution, but you're welcome! Glad that I could help